# SQL Select Query - Select rows in the table based on the latest values of column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table sample

[image]

I need to select only the latest Area Value based on latest dates that will produce this kind of output

[image]

Comment: `SELECT TOP 4 * FROM yourTable ORDER BY [date] DESC`?

Comment: it's not always top 4, area may change accordingly and may be different again from another tenant.

Comment: If OP wants to order by date ascending, do similar to Felix's comment but like this `select * from  (select top 4 * from table order by [date] desc) a order by [date]`

Comment: edited the sample table image for clearer understanding :)

Comment: How do you know which are the latest dates?

Comment: the table is order by date ascending order, then I need to filter only those with the latest Area value, but if the area is unchanged then all records of tenant will be still be shown

Comment: So the reason you show `little asia` going back to `1/5/2015` is because on `1/4/2015` the value was different? Also: **don't post screen shots of code or data!** It makes it harder for those of us who'd like to help you to create samples. Instead, enter the data into a `pre` block that we can copy/paste from.

Comment: @rickyProgrammer, the dates in your example, are they consecutive days or months? Can there be gaps in dates? For example, if you remove one row from the source data with `area=18` and `date=1/6/2015`, what would the result look like?

Comment: @VladimirBaranov YES SIR, there can be gap, like what you have given as an example. If area=18 and date=1/6/2015 were deleted, the result should still be 18, because it is the latest area as per the latest date area=18 and date=1/8/2015

Comment: @rickyProgrammer, the most difficult part of the question and query is related to your requirement to return not just one row per `tenant`, but multiple rows if `area` values repeat. So, if you delete a row with `area=18` and `date=1/6/2015`, should the result still have a row with `area=18` and **`date=1/5/2015`** or not? In other words, if there is a gap in dates, should the result stop at a gap or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the solution by Felix. I think you shouldn't partition by `area` in the first CTE. You should partition by `area` in the second CTE instead of ordering by it.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/abca0/1/0)

```
WITH 
CTE1
AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tenant ORDER BY date desc) AS rn
    FROM yourTable
)
,CTE2
AS
(
  SELECT
    *
    ,rn - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tenant, area ORDER BY rn) AS rnk
  FROM CTE1
)
SELECT
  tenant
  ,area
  ,date
  ,sales
FROM CTE2
WHERE rnk = 0
ORDER BY tenant, date desc
```

Comment: answer of Felix also produce correct answer.. How did you say that yours is more correct. How will it affect area in in first CTE? @Vladimir

Comment: @rickyProgrammer, query by Felix definitely returns different result than my variant. As I said in comments, try to run Felix query when your data has `10` instead of `20`. As for, which result **you** need, it's up to you. It would help everybody including yourself if you added more data to your sample and expected result covering different cases.

Answer (score 3):

Using a Gaps and Islands solution:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f3825/1/0)

```
WITH CteIslands AS(
    SELECT *,
        grp = DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tenant, area ORDER BY date), date)
    FROM yourTable
),
Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rnk = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY tenant ORDER BY grp DESC, area)
    FROM CteIslands
)
SELECT tenant, area, date, sales
FROM Cte WHERE rnk  = 1
```

Comment: Try to change two values of `area` from `20` to `10` and you'll see that the query doesn't return what you'd expect.

Comment: That makes sense... I am trying yours  @Vladimir

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [Windowing Functions](http://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/) or [the APPLY operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) will likely be simpler and more efficient to execute, but some people have a hard time using these, and I suspect the best result would make use of LAG/LEAD, which was not available in Sql Server 2008. Therefore I have provided a solution based purely on JOIN and GROUP BY.

First you need to know the most recent date of each tenant:

```
SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
FROM sample s1
GROUP BY s1.tenant
```

You can use this to find the `area` value from that row:

```
SELECT tenant, area, date
FROM sample s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
    FROM sample s1
    GROUP BY s1.tenant
) t on t.tenant = s.tenant and t.date = s.date
```

Now you can use this to find the most-recent date that does not have the same area:

```
SELECT s3.tenant, MAX(date) date
FROM sample s3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT tenant, area, date
    FROM sample s2
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
        FROM sample s1
        GROUP BY s1.tenant
    ) j1 on j1.tenant = s.tenant and j1.date = s.date
) j2 on j2.tenant = s3.tenant and j2.area <> s3.area
GROUP BY s3.tenant
```

And now you can use this date to select all records from each tenant with where the date is greater:

```
SELECT s4.*
FROM sample s4
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT s3.tenant, MAX(date) date
    FROM sample s3
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT tenant, area
        FROM sample s2
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
            FROM sample s1
            GROUP BY s1.tenant
        ) j1 on j1.tenant = s.tenant and j1.date = s.date
    ) j2 on j2.tenant = s3.tenant and j2.area <> s3.area
    GROUP BY s3.tenant
) j3 on j3.tenant = s4.tenant and s4.date > j4.date
```

It's worth noting hear that I *could* re-use the table aliases in the nested joins, but I often find it easier to keep track of things when writing the query if I keep them unique. You could also improve readability by moving the nested queries out to CTE's, which would help preserve the logical flow I was presenting:

```
-- Most recent date for each tenant
WITH LatestDates AS
(
    SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY tenant
),
-- the area for each tenant on that date
LatestAreas AS
(
    SELECT tenant, area
    FROM sample s
    INNER JOIN LatestDates l on l.tenant = s.tenant and l.date = s.date
),
-- the most recent date for each tenant where the area is different
LatestDateWithChangedArea AS
(
    SELECT s.tenant, MAX(date) date
    FROM sample s
    INNER JOIN LatestAreas l on l.tenant = s.tenant and l.area <> s.area
    GROUP BY s.tenant
)
-- all records for each tenant where the date is greater than that
SELECT s.*
FROM sample s
INNER JOIN LatestDateWithChangedArea l ON s.tenant = l.tenat and s.date > l.date
```

As I mentioned earlier, we can use the `APPLY` operator to simplify this even further:

```
WITH LatestDates AS
(
    SELECT tenant, MAX(date) date
    FROM sample
    GROUP BY tenant
)
SELECT s3.*
FROM LatestDates l
INNER JOIN sample s ON s.tenant = l.tenant and s.date = l.date
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 tenant, date 
  FROM sample s2
  WHERE s2.tenant = s.tenant and s2.area<>s.area
  ORDER BY s2.tenant, s2.date desc
) a
INNER JOIN sample s3 ON s3.tenant = a.tenant and s3.date > a.date
```

> **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56d7f/4)**

(Thanks to the other posters here for saving me some time putting the schema together.)

Comment: When you join by `date` in your queries you assume that there is only one row with maximum date per tenant, don't you?

Comment: That is correct, but every indication so far is that this will be the case. If needed, I could convert those JOINs to APPLYs as well, to avoid this,but JOIN is faster.

Answer (score 1):

can try this

```
//get latest date record for the tenant
WITH LatestData AS
    (SELECT tenant, area, date 
     FROM tenant_table as a
     WHERE DATE = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tenant_table as b
                    WHERE a.tenant = b.tenant)
    ),
//get latest date record for the tenant with area not the latest area
     LatestDateWithAreaChanged AS
    (SELECT tenant, max(date)
     FROM tenant_table as c INNER JOIN LatestData as D 
                            ON c.tenant = D.tenant and c.area  d.area
     GROUP BY tenant)
//get all data where date is after the last area changed     
SELECT X.* FROM tenant_table as X
INNER JOIN LatestDateWithAreaChanged as Y
ON X.tenat = Y.tenant AND X.date > Y.date
```